# Perform actions on dictionary values that match items in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value-store

I have a dictionary with 46,000 key:value pairs where each key has a 3 item list as values:

```
my dict = {key1: ['A', 'B', 'C'], key2: ['B', 'A', 'G'], key3: ['Z', 'H', 'I']......}
```

I have a list with hundreds of values:

```
L1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'D', ......]
```

How do I iterate through the list L1 and for each item in L1, match each dictionary value where value[0] matches the list item? I then wish to perform other operations on value[1] and value[2] of the dictionary only on those key:value pairs where a list item matched value[0] in the dictionary.

In the above example, the first item in L1 - 'A' would match only `key1: ['A', 'B', 'C']`.

I can't seem to figure out a way to do this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any shortcuts, you could write something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

d = {
    'key1' : ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'key2' : ['B', 'A', 'G'], 
    'key3' : ['Z', 'H', 'I']
}

l = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'D']

uniq_l = set(l) # you don't need to check duplicates twice

for key, value in d.items():
    if value[0] in uniq_l:
        print "Match", key, value

# Output:
# Match key2 ['B', 'A', 'G']
# Match key1 ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: *"How do I iterate through the list L1 ..."*  so I assume doing things in this order is important to you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {
    'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'key2': ['B', 'A', 'G'],
    'key3': ['Z', 'H', 'I'],
    'key4': ['A', 'Q', 'W'],
}

L1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'D']

lookup = defaultdict(list)

for items in my_dict.itervalues():
    lookup[items[0]].append(items[1:])

for key in L1:
    for items in lookup[key]:
        print items
```

gives:

```
['B', 'C']
['Q', 'W']
['B', 'C']
['Q', 'W']
['A', 'G']
```

Python 2.7, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> my_dict
{'key3': ['Z', 'H', 'I'], 'key2': ['B', 'A', 'G'], 'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
>>> L1 
['A', 'A', 'B', 'D']
>>> {i: {key: value for key, value in my_dict.iteritems() if value[0] == i} for i in set(L1)}
{'A': {'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C']}, 'B': {'key2': ['B', 'A', 'G']}, 'D': {}}
```

It means 'A' matches {'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C']} etc. It is a dict because of in 46000 values, i thought there could be more than one matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably build an auxilary `dict`

```
>>> mydict = {'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'key2': ['B', 'A', 'G'], 'key3': ['Z', 'H', 'I']}
>>> from collections import defaultdict>>> mydict_aux = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in mydict.items():
...     mydict_aux[v[0]].append(k)
... 
>>> mydict_aux['A']
['key1']
```